# How to exit void loop in Arduino if there is no serial data available?

Tags: android, loops, arduino-uno, void

I am building an internet controlled robot that uses 2 android phones for controlling.
The first phone is connected to Arduino Uno via USB and serves as a 3G shield
The second phone is used to control the whole thing. It sends unassigned byte to the first phone which sends it to Arduino.
The apps I uses on the phones have one problem. The joystick in the app doesn't send a specific command when its in rest. For example when I move it up it sends "1" to the phone connected to the Arduino which drives the motors forward but when I release the joystick it stops sending data however the motors on my robot still spin until I move the joystick down which sends "2" motor.run(RELEASE);

How can I stop the motors if there is no Serial Data available?

This is the code i wrote.

```
#include <AFMotor.h>
AF_DCMotor motor_left(2, MOTOR12_1KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor_right(3, MOTOR12_1KHZ);
int ledPin = 13;
int speed_min = 100; //the minimum "speed" the motors will turn - take it            lower and motors don't turn
int speed_max = 1000; //the maximum "speed" the motors will turn – you can’t put in higher
int speed_left = speed_max; // set both motors to maximum speed
int speed_right = speed_max;
int command = 0;
void setup ()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
motor_left.setSpeed(255);
motor_left.run(RELEASE);
motor_right.setSpeed(255);
motor_right.run(RELEASE);

motor_left.setSpeed(speed_left); // minimum speed 135   max speed 255
motor_right.setSpeed(speed_right); // minimum speed 135   max speed 255
}

void loop() {

if (Serial.available() > 0); 
byte command = Serial.read();

if (command == 1)
{
Serial.println("Move Forward");
digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
motor_left.run(FORWARD);
}


if (command == 2)
{
Serial.println("Stop");
digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
motor_left.run(RELEASE);
}

}
```

So basically it should do nothing if there is no data available.

Answer (score 0):

Use your code like this, it will help

```
void loop() {

            if (Serial.available() > 0) {
                byte command = Serial.read();

                if (command == 1) {
                    Serial.println("Move Forward");
                    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
                    motor_left.run(FORWARD);
                } else if (command == 2) {
                    Serial.println("Stop");
                    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
                    motor_left.run(RELEASE);

                } else {
                    //put your code to stop Motor
                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work as the motors stoppes spinning. I guess this is because of the timing. when the Arduino receives "1" the next step is to execute the else statement and as both cases are executed almost at the same time the motos don't have enough time to spin. I tried to add 100ms delay to the else but in this case each 100ms my motors stop for some time.

Comment: I've edited my answer please check
If the problem will be exactly as you described, then it should work